# I have a small chat application, when any msg arrives, automatic updating is not happening

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have simple div when messages show up on same machine but not in different machine. I want to update or refresh div in every 1 second

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function popup() {
    var a = window.open("index.aspx",'width=600,height=500,left=350,top=120')
}
</script>

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Height="200px" Width="353px" TextMode="MultiLine" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<br />
Message: <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ErrorMessage="Message cannot blank" ControlToValidate="TextBox3" runat="server" />
<br />
<br />
<div align="center">
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
</div>
```

Code behind

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string name = Session["AdminId"].ToString();

    string message = TextBox3.Text;
    string my = name + "::" + message;

    Application["msg"] = Application["msg"] + my + Environment.NewLine;

    TextBox1.Text = Application["msg"].ToString();
    TextBox3.Text = "";
}
```

Comment: It is not clear to me what your question is.  As an aside, you could probably benefit from looking into `SignalR` http://www.asp.net/signalr to push out updates, rather than constantly polling the server for them.

Comment: but i dont know signal r . cant we refresh div

Comment: You have to use SignalR, or use `setInterval()` to call your backend at regular intervals.

Comment: What exactly are you having problems with?  The polling?  You'll need to probably look into `setInterval` as Hemal stated, as well as using an AJAX request to pull data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do this using just webforms is to place your div inside updatepanel and use timer to trigger event every x sec.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional"> 
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger  ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate> 
            <!-- html -->
        </ContentTemplate> 
    </asp:UpdatePanel> 

    <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="1000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick">
    </asp:Timer>
```

However like someone wrote in comments it is worth to look at `SignalR`